# Multiple same og:title alright?

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

We have a wedding photography site that I am adding the Facebook Like button to the individual image pages.  Regarding Facebook and the og:title tag, is there a downside if the og:title tag is the same for each image in the gallery?  Example:  "John and Jane's Wedding"  Or should it be "John and Jane's Wedding - image1.jpg"?  I just want to make sure that if someone likes multiple images from the one gallery, that Facebook will treat each like correctly if the same title is used for each one, or do they each need to be unique?  Image file names are not always pretty, such as img000014.jpg, so I would like to avoid using them if it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

It may be confusing to users that different content (images in your case) have same title, but from technical perspective there is nothing wrong with it.

As long as those images have different URL's  they be treated as different objects to Facebook OpenGraph (since objects are identified by URL's not titles).